# Magento 1.9.2.2: Rename Category heading to Sub-Category in Left Side Bar

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to rename my heading "Category" to "Sub-Category" in left side bar under "Browse by".

Could any one please help me. How and Where could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer after some research.

app->code-> core-> Mage-> Catalog-> Model-> Filter-> Category.php

Find: 
return Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Category');

Replace with:
return Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Sub Category');